# How to add text in front of input field

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having trouble trying to add text to the left of an input field and below a label.

I'm using Bootstrap 4.3.1. My html looks like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<!-- some markup in here -->
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
        <label>Sensor URI:</label>
            http://<input value="" type="text" id="sensor_uri" min="15" max="1440" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks something like this:

[image]

I've tried various things like enclosing "http://" in different element (`<p>`, `div>`, etc) without any success. Ideally I want "http://" in front of the input field like this so that the user can't edit it:

[image]

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 2 things -

1. use the `form-control-inline` class on the input so it will appear in line with the "http://" text
2. wrap the input and text in a block element such as a `<div>` to make it appear on its own line underneath the label.

- *Note* - you have an extra `row` div  without any `col`s - this is not valid so I removed it below.

**See a working snippet here:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  <!-- some markup in here -->
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  <label>Sensor URI:</label>
  <div class="inputwrapper">http:// <input value=" " type="text " id="sensor_uri " min="15 " max="1440 " class="form-control-inline" required/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add grids inside row for label & input

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<!-- some markup in here -->
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">   <label>Sensor URI:</label></div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">     http://  </div> <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-10"><input value="" type="text" id="sensor_uri" min="15" max="1440" class="form-control" required/> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That does work although there is bit of a gap between 'http://' and the input field.

Answer (score 0):

How about flexbox?

```
<div class='container'>
<div>
    <label>Sensor URI:</label>
</div>
<div>
    <span>http://</span>
    <input value="" type="text" id="sensor_uri" min="15" max="1440" class="form-control" required />
</div>
```

the css:

```
.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:
I will give you a good idea and it's something you are trying to achieve.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 my-1">
      <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername">Username</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">http://</div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername" placeholder="Username">
      </div>
    </div>
```